# No picture uploaded in codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I'm fighting with this already 1 and a half hour, but can't find a problem. I'm using codeigniter and upload function, but it always fails to upload -

Controller -

```
  // Uploads the picture to server  
    public function uploadPicture()
    {
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));  
    $this->load->helper('url'); 
        $config['upload_path'] = './images/pictures/';
        $config['allowed_types'] = 'gif|jpg|png';
        $config['max_size'] = '700';
        $config['max_width']  = '1024';
        $config['max_height']  = '768';

        $this->load->library('upload', $config);

        $this->upload->do_upload();

        if ( ! $this->upload->do_upload())
        {
            $data = array('upload_data' => $this->upload->data());      

            var_dump($data);
      //redirect('/profile/changePicture', 'refresh');
        }
        else
        {
      redirect('/profile/changePicture', 'refresh');            
        }
    }
```

view -

```
  <form class="fix-this form" method="post" action="/savieno/profile/uploadPicture" enctype="multipart/form-data">
                    <div class="formfield">                     
                      <label id="current-password-error" class="input-error" style="display: none;"></label>        
                      <span class="profile">Tava bilde: </span>                                   
                        <input id="picture" name="picture" class="with-label" style="width: 270px;" type="file" placeholder="Tava bilde" />
                      <label>*</label>
    </div>                      
                  <input type="submit" id="submit" value="Labot Profilu" name="edit" class="fix-this" />         
  </form>
```

After I select either no picture, or if I select a picture, it gives me var_dump with detials -

```
array
  'upload_data' => 
    array
      'file_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'file_type' => string '' (length=0)
      'file_path' => string './images/pictures/' (length=18)
      'full_path' => string './images/pictures/' (length=18)
      'raw_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'orig_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'client_name' => string '' (length=0)
      'file_ext' => string '' (length=0)
      'file_size' => string '' (length=0)
      'is_image' => boolean false
      'image_width' => string '' (length=0)
      'image_height' => string '' (length=0)
      'image_type' => string '' (length=0)
      'image_size_str' => string '' (length=0)
```

What could be the problem?

Comment: How does it fail? What happens? Do you get an error?

Comment: Nope no error, it just loads the var_dump... check the controller, it says if it fails to upload, then load var_dump otherwise redirect. ;/

Comment: You're doing `$this->upload->do_upload()` twice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$config['upload_path'] = './images/pictures/';` be sure that the path you write is correct and it has the proper 777 right to write the file into.

Also, as Kristian wrote, you are are doing the `$this->upload->do_upload();` upload part twice.

To check for errors, you can do this:

```
<?php
if(!$this->upload->do_upload())        
{
    echo $this->upload->display_error(); 
    return FALSE;
}
else
{
    $data = $this->upload->data();
    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Oh, yeah, I know that, that was just to check, if it gives any error, but it doesn't. Ok gonna check it twice, if it's on localhost, can I wrtie the full part http://localhost/images/pictures/ ? In additional, if I'm checking it on localhost do I really need to set permissions?

Comment: You must set permissions in wherever you are testing. Simply you can create an `uploads` folder in the main folder of you CI project, set permissions and try again.

Comment: Hmm, now how can I set permissions on localhost? :P I'm using Windows 7, and I don't have server setup on localhost, so I must set up server, and then connect via filezilla?

Comment: Just set write to folder. You can do that rigth click over the folder->Properties->Security and set rights.

Comment: Aha! Wether I select file or no it gives - You did not select a file to upload. In additional all directories have write permissions ;)!

Comment: lol - $this->upload->do_upload('my_uploaded_file');  did the trick. my_uploaded_file is the name of the input field ;)! cheers, Accepted your answer, thanks ;)!